# terraform import: How to avoid errors on reimporting in automated scripts

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Goal:

1. Reserve a static ip (permanent) for ever in gcp console: e.g "ip-drupal-1"
2. In terraform submodule "./module_drupal" make use of that 'ip-drupal-1'
3. When 'terraform destroy' is invoked, the the ip-drupal-1 must stay reserved in gcp.  If static-ip gets destroyed, this will generate another new one, and I have to update DNS records.

The below procedure did not achieve that goal. Is there any sample code out there?

I added a "terraform import -var-file="main.tfvars" google_compute_address.ip-drupal-1 ip-drupal-1",

so it imports that static ip each time I invoke that shellscript.

How to avoid this error : "to import to this address, you must first remove ..."

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to repeatedly import the same resource?

Answer (score 2):

To specifically address this maybe add a `terraform state rm` followed by the object id right before the import.

See [this](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/state/rm.html) for info about terraform state rm.

Depending on how you are handling your automation that might work.

Comment: This did not help in achieving my goal. Edited my question to clarify further.

Comment: Ok can you share your current sequence? It seems you should be able to achieve what you want by removing the resource from the state file, then destroying and then adding it back

Comment: Just realised the way we achieve this is by isolating the IP address management in a different directory. You'd create it once, in a separate tf, then have your modules reference that resource everytime and never touch it again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing

1. In the infra-update.sh, I added 'terraform state rm' before importing.

infra-createorupdate.sh

```sh
terraform init
terraform state list
STATIC_IP_NAME="ip-base"
terraform state rm "google_compute_address.${STATIC_IP_NAME}"
terraform import -var-file="main.tfvars" google_compute_address.${STATIC_IP_NAME}  ${STATIC_IP_NAME}

read -s -n 1 -p "Press any key to continue . . ."

terraform plan -var-file="main.tfvars" -out plan.out
#echo -ne '\007'
read -s -n 1 -p "Press any key to APPLY .. Press Ctrl C to abort"
echo ""
terraform apply plan.out
#echo -ne '\007'
```

Then in my root main.tf I defined the address as prevent_destroy = true

main.tf

```
resource "google_compute_address" "ip-base" { # see terraform import in deploy.sh
  name = "ip-base"
  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true #DO NOT DELETE STATIC-IP
  }
}


# Call vm_micro
module "vm-base" {
  source = "./_module-vm-micro"
  vm_instance_name = "base"
  custom_static_ip = google_compute_address.ip-base.address 

  #from predefined
  #CPU/RAM
  vm_size = var.org_micro
  #where
  deploy_env = var.deploy_env
  zone  = var.zone
  #disk
  boot_image = var.disk_image_coscloud
  disk_type = var.disk_hdd
  disk_size = var.disk_20_gb
  #login
  login_key_file = var.ssh_pubkey_file
  login_user = var.ssh_username
}
```

Another alternative:

Perhaps I can also save money by not using static-ip. Instead, in the boot-startupscript.sh, I could make an Dynamic DNS api call to update the dynamic api to dns. I've to experiment with that, hope there is some example code.

https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6147083?hl=en#zippy=%2Cusing-the-api-to-update-your-dynamic-dns-record